# If $(\Omega, F, m)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space, show the following

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The problem is

Let $\mu$ be outer measure (extended) from $m$. Let $G$ be all $\mu$-measurable subsets of $\Omega$ (constructed using Caratheodory's Extension), $E\in G$, then show that there are $M,N\in F$ such that

$$
M\subset E \subset N
$$

with

$$
\mu(N\setminus E)=\mu(E\setminus M)=0
$$

I am happy with the problem if $\mu(E)<\infty$ (basically definition chasing), and I've also found out that existence of $M$ follows from the existence of $N$. But if $\mu(E)=\infty$ everything just breaks down, and it seems that I've got to use the fact that $\Omega$ is $\sigma$-finite with respect to $m$. So I have to find a suitable candidate for $N$, but for over a half an hour of thinking I've got to admit that I'm getting to nowhere.

I understand that being $\sigma$-finite implies that there exists an increasing sequence of sets $E_n\in F$ such that $E_n\uparrow \Omega$ and $m(E_n)<\infty$ for all $n$. But I can't seem to find a link between this and the problem.

It'd be nice if I could get some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint
$m(E)=m(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n\cap E)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}m(E_n\cap E)$

So, you must prove that you can cover each $E_n\cap E$ with the desired sets. (Which is finite by monotonicity)

Comment: Ah, so $m(E_n\cap E)$ is finite for each $n$, and therefore by definition $\mu(E_n\cap E)$ is finite for each $n$, and I can apply the result since now meausre is finite, and then I can combine it up to account for $E$ itself?

Comment: Yes, basically. Cover each one, take the union of all of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I got it!

Comment: I am struggling with the problem, I would be grateful if you could kindly elaborate. What could be a cover of $E_n \cap E$?